# Set triggers for a custom event when addEventListener is called

Tags: javascript, events, dom, addeventlistener, custom-event

When `thing.addEventListener(...)` is called with a custom event in javascript, is there a way of running some code to set triggers on the thing?  Here is an example:

```
var bong = new CustomEvent("bong");
element1.addEventListener('bong', (e) => console.log(`${e.target.id} bonged`));
```

Now I want `bong` to be triggered whenever certain things happen to element.  Say, for example, `mousedown` and `mouseup`.  I could write:

```
var bong = new CustomEvent("bong");
function setBongTriggers(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => e.target.dispatchEvent(bong));
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => e.target.dispatchEvent(bong));
}

element1.addEventListener('bong', (e) => console.log(`${e.target.id} bonged`));
setBongTriggers(element);
```

But I an going to have to do this for many elements and I don't want to have to call `setBongTriggers` for every one.  Is there no way of telling `addEventListener` to set the triggers?

Comment: The question is ... why? Why wouldn't you just call a regular old function instead of using custom events ?

Comment: There is a certain behaviour I want to characterize.  When that behaviour happens to one element, I want o do X.  When it happens to another, I want to do Y and so on.  One thing I could do is to write my own "addEventListener" but that is ugly as it duplicates something that is already in the language.  So I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: I think the answer is no then, but you could just iterate over elements and set the event listeners etc.